# Powershell - How can I exclude All Files in the Get-childitem command and include Get-Adgroupmember

Tags: powershell

Still new to powershell and I am needing to do a security report and find all the permissions applied to all folders within a drive and then export it onto an excel document. The command I've got so far includes files but all the files are setup to inherit from the folder they are in. What  im hoping to do is for it to ignore all the files that include .txt, .msg, .doc, .xlsx etc etc.

Also hoping with the groups it pulls in to use the Get-Adgroupmember on it so that I can see who is in the group and also export this to the excel file in the column next to it.

```
$FilePath = Get-childitem "\\C:\Downloads\TEST" -Recurse
ForEach ($File in $FilePath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $File.FullName
    ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) {
        $Properties = [ordered]@{'File Name' = $File.FullName; 'Group/User' = $Access.IdentityReference; 'Permissions' = $Access.FileSystemRights; 'Inherited' = $Access.IsInherited }
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties | Export-Csv "C:\Downloads\FinanceResult.csv" -append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

Comment: "Also hoping with the groups it pulls in to use the Get-Adgroupmember on it so that I can see who is in the group and also export this to the excel file in the column next to it." - can you provide an example of the desired output CSV? Groups can have both users or other groups as members, how do you want to indicate that in the output? Should the group members be shown with their username/samaccountname? Name? SID? Something else?

Comment: Simply remove all access control entries that are inherited to get only uninherited. `$Access.IsInherited` give the information. For groups @MathiasR.Jessen is right, you may output one folder on a line, but how do you want to represent the members of a group in the column? Members may be direct and nested in subgroups, and you should think to nested groups that may loop on themselves.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen So for the CSV need it to say File path name, what permission group is applied to it, and then the Active Directory usernames of the people in said group.

Comment: @Elder95 Right, but you said you want the group information in one column. There could 0 "people" in the group. There could be 1000. Should the column contain a semi-colon separated list of user names? A tab-separated list of emails? A base64-encoded JSON string?

Comment: Why did yo prefic the path with a double backslash? `Get-childitem "\\C:\Downloads\TEST"`. It's a local path, not a UNC path

Comment: @Theo the real folder will be a UNC path i just copied it out for security that's all just missed removing the \\

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The biggest group that should be applied to the folder shouldn't have more than 100 people so a semi-colon separating them would be best for what I need

Comment: @Elder95 A semi-colon separated list of _what_? Usernames? Display names? GUIDs? SIDs?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Display names would be better, but usernames if it makes things more simple